# How to allow javascript tasks to run across multiple screens on Cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm working on a mobile app with Cordova.  When the user starts up the app, I'd like to kick off a non-blocking function to load data from the server.  This function can take up to a few seconds.

I'm using the leecrossley/cordova-plugin-background-task plugin.  It works fine if I stay on the page that kicked off the function.  If I change pages, it stops the function.

Any thoughts?

- Jon

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as if you are experiencing web-view-throttling!
Cordova uses the Chromium web engine so it usually follows all of the performance settings implemented in the chrome browser.

You can read some more about the throttling issue here:
https://thenextweb.com/apps/2017/01/26/chrome-throttle-background-tabs-google/#.tnw_WIKDX2EX

> The solution to your problem is

to create a main page to function as the core of your application. This main page will always be open 'thus saving your from scripts being stopped when a new page is loaded.

> For app pages, i recommend either:

creating a separate .html file per app page, then load those external pages into your main app page via an iFrame ...the src of the iFrame can be updated via javascript. (the downside to this approach is that you will need to write additional javascript to monitor and control the events that happen inside of your iFrames -from the main page.)

> or

Build a very big single page application; wrapping all of your app pages in divs.. then create a javascrip menu function that manages what page is displayed and what page is hidden. (This may result in a massive .html page but this method will allow you to run any number of non-blocking scripts the device can handle at once.) <-- This is the method i have been using for over three years, i also add some iFrames to include special page modules when needed. CSS and JavaScript can be loaded from external files.

I believe most cordova developers actually use this single-page method!

Comment: Great, thanks very much for the detailed answer!  I'll look into it and see if these can work for me.  I have an existing app, pretty substantial.

Comment: No problem. Do let me know if it helped!